# How can I define bracket pair colorization for brackets inside comments for a VS Code language extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, syntax-highlighting, grammar, textmate

I'm making the TextMate grammar for a language to get syntax highlighting. This is the rule for `@link` tags in doc comments:

```json
"scopeName": "source.amx.pawn",
  "patterns": [
    {
      "name": "comment.block.documentation.amx.pawn",
      "begin": "/\\*\\*(?!/)",
      "end": "\\*/",
      "patterns": [{ "include": "#docblock" }]
    },
    // more patterns...
  ],
  "repository": {
    "docblock": {
      "patterns": [
        "match": "({)(@)(link|linkcode|linkplain)\\s+(\\w+)\\s+(.*)(})",
        "captures": {
          "1": { "name": "punctuation.definition.bracket.amx.pawn" },
          "2": { "name": "punctuation.docblock.at.amx.pawn" },
          "3": { "name": "storage.type.class.docblock.tag.amx.pawn" },
          "4": { "name": "variable.other.docblock.link.amx.pawn" },
          "5": { "name": "entity.name.type.instance.docblock.amx.pawn" },
          "6": { "name": "punctuation.definition.bracket.amx.pawn" },
        }
      ]
    },
    // more stuff...
  }
}
```

Everything is colorized correctly, except for the curly braces. They have the punctuation color (which is what I specified in the rule).

[image: my textmate rule]

but I assumed vscode would apply the bracket pair colorizer on top of that anyway, like it does on typescript, for example.

[image: typescript textmate rule]

As you can see, in typescript it has the bracket pair colorization applied.

If I inspect the editor tokens and scopes, these are the textmate scopes for the curly braces with my grammar:

```
punctuation.definition.bracket.amx.pawn
comment.block.documentation.amx.pawn
source.amx.pawn
```

and these are the scopes of the curly braces in typescript:

```
punctuation.definition.bracket.curly.end.jsdoc
entity.name.type.instance.jsdoc
comment.block.documentation.ts
source.ts
```

The only difference is the `entity.name.type.instance` scope, but I think thats a trailing scope from the previous token, so I'm guessing the bracket pair colorizer doesn't care about those scopes.

How can I achieve the same result as with the typescript grammar?

Comment: hm. https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/132249 and [its completing commit](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/commit/eb5e38bb0bc5e96a472c2404dfde5d41346f868b) might mean that what you're observing with bracket-pair colourization in comments is actually a bug. Actually, when I just tried it with `/**\n * {{{@link something something}}}\n */`, I got a bug where it was enabled for all three brackets when switching language mode to JSX or TSX, but after a while, that behaviour stopped happening, which just tickles my bug suspicion even more.

Comment: So I probably shouldn't care? I must admit sometimes I waste time on little details

Comment: I have no clue :P I could be wrong in my analysis (as you can see from my deleted answer, it wouldn't be the first time). maybe I'm missing info.

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same issue and solved it by defining a language configuration that included a [definition for brackets](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/language-configuration-guide#brackets-definition).

```json
// package.json
{
  "name": "langname",
  // other stuff ...
  "contributes": {
    "languages": [
      {
        "id": "langid",
        // other stuff...
        "configuration": "./language-configuration.json"
      }
    ],
    // other stuff ...
  }
}
```

```json
// language-configuration.json
{
  "brackets": [
    ["{", "}"],
    ["[", "]"],
    ["(", ")"],
    // other tokens you want to colorize
  ],
  // other stuff...
}
```